# Angular Form is always initially invalid

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I am using the following form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  ...
  <div class="col-xs-12 nopadding">
    <button class="btn loginbutton" type="submit" [disabled]="!submitEnabled()">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the component ts, the `submitEnabled` looks like this:

```
submitEnabled(){
    let enabled = false;
    if(this.form.valid){
      enabled = true;
    }
    return enabled;
  }
```

Alternatively I could have written `[disabled]="this.form.valid"` (I am using reactive forms, and `form`is my variable for the form).

Note: I am using Material as UI Framework for the inputs (could be unimportant)

**Problem:**
Initially, my form is always invalid. This form is about a login. The browser autofills the values and therefore touches the form. This results in the form being *touched* and *dirty*. At the same time, the form still remains *invalid*, although the form contains valid data. If I click anywhere on the site or inside the form, the validity seemingly gets checked again and the form switches to valid. Problem with this: The "Login"-Button initially is always disabled, even if the form contains valid data.

Is there any way to force the validation check after auto fill, or am I missing something to trigger the validity check in other ways?

**EDIT:**
In the form I am using, I have a password type field. This field is the one initially always set to invalid.
**EDIT2:**
The password field is initially untouched and pristine, but it contains valid data...

Comment: browser auto-fill isn't **user interaction**, so it won't trigger a validity check.

Comment: @Claies thanks for the input, but it seems to differ for the plain text input and the password input

Comment: How so? You said it is untouched and pristine with valid data; that sounds like data entered without user interaction to me... the form will remain invalid, since the value in the field isn't reflected in the model yet, until user interaction occurs.  The model is pristine (null) even though the input is not pristine.

Comment: i can see that people commenting are actually dodging the problem :D

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got the same problem.
I'm initializing my form with valid data, and I can even extract that data from the FormGroup, but until I manually change something in the UI (to the same value it already was) it's 'INVALID'